# Creating a text Input in react with a "value" makes it read only?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function

```
function CreateTextInput({ id, placeholder, defaultValue, value }) {    
        return (
            <input
                type="text"
                name={id}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                value={value}
            //onChange={onChange}
            />
        );
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
Use like this: <CreateTextInput id="fieldID1" defaultValue="fieldDefaultValue" value="fieldValue" />
```

But it results in the field becoming read only. as in I can select the value in the field, but cant edit it. When I don't have the "value" parameter in there, then it's editable.

I know I could use defaultValue instead, but was just experimenting. Just wondering if this is normal behavior?

AND, in the case of setting the value on create of the object, what's the difference between defaultValue and value anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just wondering if this is normal behavior?

Yes, this is [expected behavior](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable):

> If you pass `value` without `onChange`, it will be impossible to type into
> the input. When you control an input by passing some `value` to it, you
> force it to always have the value you passed. So if you pass a state
> variable as a `value` but forget to update that state variable
> synchronously during the onChange event handler, React will revert the
> input after every keystroke back to the `value` that you specified.

So when you provide a `value` prop, your input will reflect the value supplied in that prop, thus it becomes read-only unless you update the `value` prop accordingly with `onChange`. By doing that, you're making your input a [controlled input](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable).

---

> AND, in the case of setting the value on create of the object, what's
> the difference between defaultValue and value anyway?

If you provide a `value` then there is typically no need to provide a `defaultValue` as well, as your `defaultValue` will be overwritten by what you specify in the `value` prop:

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(
  <input type="text" value="used" defaultValue="not used" />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In the example case above, it's only if `value` becomes `undefined` or `null` where `defaultValue` kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `useState`.

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function yourComponent(){
const [value,setValue] = useState("")

return (
            <input
                type="text"
                name={id}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                value={value}
                onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)}
            />
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you edit what's in the box the new value doesn't replace the `value`. You need to use the `onChange` handler and update the `value` with the new value -- and it needs to be *observable* i.e., stored in `state`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute `readOnly`
when value is not `undefined` (you can remove it or explicitly set it to `undefined`), the input become controlled component (the value of it is from the value attribute)
Other cases, the input use the default value attribute, and you can edit it (if there is no readOnly attribute)

```
<input value={undefined} defaultValue="default" readOnly />
```

Answer (score 1):

You must send an onChange function to the component

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const onchange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <CreateTextInput id="fieldID1" defaultValue="fieldDefaultValue" value={value} onChange={onchange} />
  )
```